# Implement Stack using Queues

Tags: debugging, stack, address-sanitizer

I am tried to solve this problem but can't rectify number of times. I replace what I know

```
class MyStack {
public:
    int *arr;
    int tops;
    
    MyStack() {
        arr=new int(25);
        int tops=-1;
    }
    
    void push(int x) {
        arr[++tops]=x;
    }
    
    int pop() {
        
        tops--;
        return arr[tops];
        
    }
    
    int top() {
        return arr[tops];
    }
    
    bool empty() {
        bool a;
        a= tops==-1?true:false;
        return a;
    }
};
```

When I'm using some other complier it works and I got perfect.
Why the problem repit again? I got two problem has same error.

[image]

Comment: When pushing, it looks like you are incrementing the index before adding the new value. This means that the index will always point to the value just pushed. Therefore, when pulling, you need to take the value out, then decrement the index - the opposite of what you're doing.

Comment: A stack is fundamentally different from a queue, so you cannot implement a stack using a queue reasonably.

Answer (score 0):

All your functions in `MyStack` (except `empty()`) have chances of causing illegal memory access. Here's some simple driver code for your class that would cause crashes.

```
int main()
{
    MyStack stack;
    int x = stack.pop(); //will crash
    int x = stack.top();//will crash
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
        stack.push(i); //will crash at the last push()
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You need to protect:

1. reads to `arr[]` member via `top()` and `pop()` by always validating if `tops` is pointing to a valid value. If it's `-1` it would cause a crash while accessing `arr[-1]` due to a heap-buffer *underflow*.
2. writes to `arr[]` via `push()` by always verifying `tops` and whether it's within the bounds of the allocated memory for `arr[]`. In the code, `arr[]` is backed by 25 integer elements. What if there are 26 elements pushed to the stack? The last would be a heap-buffer *overflow*.